# Zend like modules in cakephp

Tags: php, zend-framework, cakephp

is there a way to do modules in cakephp like zend framework modules ? In zend framework, you have a folder 'modules' like following structure:

```
/application/modules/admin
/application/modules/site
/application/modules/service
```

and it's routed in this way:

```
http://myapp.local/admin
http://myapp.local/service
http://myapp.local/ -- to site module (default).
```

The models are shared, just controlllers are module specific.
How can I achieve this in CakePHP? There's a better way to do this type things in cake ?

Thanks in advANCE

Comment: If you can't get an answer here, try the cakephp irc. I found them useful in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this http://book.cakephp.org/view/950/Prefix-Routing  . With that, I can have same experience as Zend modules.

Answer (score 0):

if you use plugins, you can do it, as you have shown above.
[cakephp plugins](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1112/Creating-a-Plugin)